# Google Sheets API: get the name of the tab that was last edited

Tags: python, google-sheets, google-drive-api

I'm trying to find out which tab in the spreadsheet was last changed.

I have a google sheet with multiple tabs shared among multiple users. I can detect when a user makes a change like this:

```
def testChanges(self):
    response = self.service.revisions().list(fileId='some-file-id').execute()
    revs = response.get('revisions',[])
    if not len(revs):
        return
    revID = revs[-1].get('id')
    response = self.service.revisions().get(
                            fileId='some-file-id',
                            revisionId=revID,
                            fields='kind, id, modifiedTime, lastModifyingUser'
                            ).execute()
```

And I get a response:

```
{
  "kind": "drive#revision",
  "id": "12",
  "modifiedTime": "2018-09-17T20:10:41.330Z",
  "lastModifyingUser": {
    "kind": "drive#user",
    "displayName": "USER NAME",
    "me": true,
    "permissionId": "08921584708523400585",
    "emailAddress": "email.address@gmail.com"
  }
```

Now I need to process the tab that the user just changed. How can I figure that out? I've checked [Drive documentation](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/revisions) and [Sheets API](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/samples/reading), but so far no luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe this is supported or possible from the REST API. You will probably need to create an [installed edit](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable) trigger, and use it to log the [edit event object](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events#edit) (e.g. POSTing it to a URL, appending it to some "sentinel" spreadsheet, etc.). You can combine this with your current `revisions` method to know who performed the modification (since the user identity is generally restricted information unless you are in the same GSuite domain).

An example, that writes the data to a designated spreadsheet.

```
function installedEdit(e) {
  const edited = e.range,
        sheet = edited.getSheet();
  const row = [
    new Date(),         // Time of the edit
    e.source.getId(),   // id of the edited workbook.
    e.source.getName(),
    sheet.getName(),    // edited sheet name
    sheet.getSheetId(), // gridid for REST API
    edited.getA1Notation(),
    edited.oldValue !== undefined ? edited.oldValue : "",
    edited.value !== undefined ? edited.value : ""
  ];
  try { row.push(e.user.getEmail()); }
  catch (e) { row.push("Unknown User"); }
  // Log this row somehow
  SpreadsheetApp.openById("some spreadsheet id").getSheetByName("Edit log").appendRow(row);
}
```

You could create this function in a standalone Apps Script project and [programmatically install](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable#managing_triggers_programmatically) this function as the edit trigger for various spreadsheets you need to watch.

Comment: I think that this is a good workaround. For example, how about using [the custom properties of Drive API](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/properties)? In this case, it puts the values by GAS using the installable trigger, and the values can be retrieved by python using Drive API without adding and modifying scopes and APIs. Because the required information is only a little, I thought it might be able to be used. If this was not useful for OP's situation, please ignore this.

Answer (score -1):

You may make a for loop to scan all tabs (every few seconds) and store the modifiedTime for all of them in a table. Program the loop to compare the current modifiedTime for each tab with the value you have from the last scan. When there is a mismatch, that's mean the current tab is modified.

Just an idea.

Comment: how can I get modified time for a specific tab?

Comment: I see from the response you submitted there is a modifiedTime field.  ( "modifiedTime": "2018-09-17T20:10:41.330Z"). You have this field for each tab right?. This value will change every time the tab updated.